# How to install Python module living in a private Git repository in Heroku app?

Tags: git, heroku, github, pip, ssh-keys

I wrote a Python package `packagename` on my local workstation, it looks like this:

```
packagename/
packagename/setup.py
packagename/modulename.py
```

I installed `packagename` from a `virtualenv` with this shell command:

```
virt-env$ bin/pip install path/to/packagename
```

I put `packagename` in a private Github repository, a location like this:

```
github.com/username/packagename.git
```

I installed `modulename` from a `virtualenv` with this shell command:

```
virt-env$ bin/pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/username/packagename#egg=modulename
```

...after I [created an SSH public key and attached it to my Github account](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey).

In the Heroku app repository, where I want to use `modulename`, I added a line to `requirements.txt` like this:

```
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/username/packagename#egg=modulename
```

**But how do I authorize Heroku with an SSH key?**

I found that Github has something called [deploy keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys), but I can't figure out how to marry the deploy key to Heroku after adding it to the GitHub repository. I assume that there aren't many examples of how to do this because they are all hidden in private repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. [Change the Python buildpack](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/11/13/hacking-buildpacks) so it knows how to clone private repositories.
2. [Clone the module locally, add it to version control](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb) and push it with your app.

I recommend #2.